# Input through node JS in Terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js, input

I am trying to make a program in Node.JS that will display some text, using `console.log("");`, then wait for the user to input some commands. First of all, I want to run this through the Linux Terminal on Cloud9 IDE, which does not pause long enough to input anything. Second of all, I want it to be like its own little command line. (I mean respond to certain case-sensitive commands, and ignore anything else.) Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Hey Brendan, welcome to StackOverflow. Please post some code, and give us some context on your own attempts. This will improve the quality of your question. For help, see “[How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.

Answer (score 0):

Check out prompt. https://www.npmjs.com/package/prompt It works like:

```
    var prompt = require('prompt');

  prompt.start();

  prompt.get(['hello'], function (err, result) {
    console.log('you typed ' + result.hello);
  });
```

Will do:

```
    $ nodejs prompt.js 
prompt: hello:  world
you typed world
```

Happy coding ^^